# sin, cos, tan not accurate

Tags: floating-point, trigonometry, floating-accuracy

Why does `sinl` give incorrect results when the argument is near a non-zero multiple of pi? Why does `sinl` give incorrect results when the argument is large? The following code illustrates that.

Note that the digits used to initialize variable pi do not exactly match any 64-bit long double value. The compiler chooses the nearest value, which is `3.14159265358979323851280895940618620443274267017841339111328125`. The expected sine value can be found using libquadmath, gnu MPFR lib, or an online calculator such as http://www.ttmath.org/online_calculator.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
    {
    volatile long double pi = 3.14159265358979323846L;
    volatile long double big = 9223372035086174241L;
    volatile long double expected1 = -5.0165576126683320235E-20L;
    volatile long double expected2 = -4.2053336735954077951E-10L;
    double result;
    double ex1 = expected1, ex2 = expected2;

    result = sinl (pi);
    printf("expected: %g, \nreturned: %g\n\n", ex1, result);
    result = sinl (big);
    printf("expected: %g, \nreturned: %g\n\n", ex2, result);
    return 0;
    }
```

I am using gcc 4.7.3. The use of volatile keeps the compiler from replacing the `sinl()` call with a hard-coding result. My computer has an Intel Core i7 processor and runs Windows. I am printing the results as double instead of long double because the mingw port of gcc I use does not support printing long double. Here is the program output:

```
expected: -5.01656e-020,
returned: -5.42101e-020

expected: -4.20533e-010,
returned: -0.011874
```

Comment: Required reading: [_What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic_](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (particularly for your second test). Also, it would help to use a value of pi that is accurate to the last bit, rather than the approximation in your code. (Unfortunately, `M_PI` is a `double`, not a `long double`. Try using `pi = acosl(-1.0L);`) Where did the expected values come from? The sine of PI should be 0.

Comment: @TedHopp:  For God's sake, if you're going to link to that page and call it "required reading", at least read it.

Comment: @tmyklebu - I've read it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @ScottD: If your question is based on more than the very, very common "I don't get exact results from floating-point calculations, why can that be", you should state so clearly in the question. Otherwise many people will misunderstand.

Comment: @TedHopp: Nothing; it's a very good introduction.  But you obviously never read or understood the page you linked to.  The value of `pi` used in the code *is* precise enough.  And the sine of the closest floating-point number to pi will *not* be floating-point zero.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy:  He's asking why he gets wildly incorrect results from a library function.  And he's doing it loudly and clearly.  Not sure I see the problem.

Comment: @TedHopp Either `3.14159265358979323846L` **is** the closest `long double` to π, or the OP has a compiler problem (note: the OP has a compiler problem, just probably not this one). There is an approximation, but this value is “accurate to the last bit” in the sense that you need more bits for a better approximation. The sine of π should be zero, but `sinl(3.14159265358979323846L)` can be expected to be up to ULP_longdouble(3)/2 away from zero.

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy: OK, I updated the first sentence to give a better description of the problem. I also tried to explain the difference between the source code pi= value and what is actually passed to sinl, and then ways to come up with the expected value.

Comment: @ScottD Is the difference b/n -0.0000000000000000000501656 and -0.0000000000000000000542101 is such crucial in your application ? IMO, those 2 values are *practically* 0 (unless you deal w/ sub-particles physics)

Comment: @Shmil, Though small, the numbers you list are bigger than the mass in grams of an entire uranium atom. They are 300+ orders of magnitude bigger than the smallest normal DP number. The relative difference is big, same as if I break a ten and give you only $9.25. The difference between these two numbers is larger than the division error that resulted in the 1994 Intel Pentium recall.

Answer (score 3):

The inaccuracy can be traced to the fsin processor instruction used by the sinl library code. The instructions fsin, fcos, and fptan are not accurate to 1.0 ulp as Intel claims:
http://notabs.org/fpuaccuracy/

Comment: So, if I'm reading the graphs correctly, one, at least partial, remedy would be to use modulo to restrict the value in <0, 2Pi), where the precision is higher?

Comment: Yes. But I think doing the modulo operation with the needed accuracy will not be straight-forward. One challenge is that a long double cannot a good enough approximation of pi.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve 1 ULP accuracy for multiples of pi, the internal constant M_PI should have about 106 bit accuracy (or 128 for long doubles).

In the reduction stage a perfect implementation would have to somehow generate the missing 53 or 64 bits of accuracy after subtracting `(x - M_PI)`, as an naive implementation would calculate this interim value as zero. The problem of course gets bigger and bigger, when the argument will be a large integer multiply of that non-zero.

The internal precision of 66 bits for M_PI is not enough for 1 ULP accuracy. Then again, one could re-read the claims and check if the accuracy of 1 ULP was claimed relative to the result, or the argument.

Comment: Unless there's a clever way to do it, I think you need far, far more than 128 bits of pi to do argument reduction for trig functions.  Computing `0x1p16382` mod pi with 64 bits of precision would seem to need pi to about 16450 bits.  Maybe a few more if there's an integer multiple of pi that's approximated particularly well by a `long double`.

Comment: Yes, once you go above the range of long longs perfectly representable as doubles, one needs about one additional bit per exponent. I just assumed from the context of the question (x = 2^63-some) that one wasn't really expecting to get accurate result of sin(10^6000).

Comment: Implementations of trigonometric functions of reasonable quality do not use `M_PI` for reduction. Something like the Payne-Hanek algorithm is used. Essentially, a multiplication by 1/π is performed, but it is a specialized multiplication that returns only the fraction bits, discarding the integer value. Since the integer value is discarded, not all bits of 1/π are needed. The highest bit needed is determined by the magnitude of the input operand, and the lowest bit is determined by some number-theoretic properties (how close some numbers in the interval are to multiples of π/2).

Answer (score 1):

GNU libc's documentation (accessible by running `info libc math errors`) lists a 1 ulp "known error" for `cosl` on x86 and "x86_64/fpu."  It doesn't document anything for `sinl`.  I can reproduce similarly huge errors for `cosl` around pi/2 on my x86_64 machine.

Perhaps you should report this as a documentation bug to the glibc and Linux man pages folks; I can't imagine it's worth implementing the "right" fix.

If you really want a fast and accurate `sinl`, I'm not too sure where to look.  [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/) does `sin` (the variant for `double`s).  [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) will handle it, but it'll be many times slower than `fsin`.

Comment: I gave libquadmath a try. Of course it easily gets the expected result after rounding its 128 bit answer down to 64-bit precision. It is slower than the processor instruction as expected. I measure 15X slower for the argument near pi, and 60 times slower for the big argument.

Comment: @ScottD: Cool.  Thanks for the pointer; I didn't know about libquadmath.